# Replace o-Rings on Keg?

Tags: keg

I have not had my kegging system for long but have had a good amount of use from it already. How often should all the o-Rings or small little black seals be replaced? They seem fine now but I would hate to have issues later just because I didn't keep up on the maintenance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep a few spares on-hand. When a keg starts to leak track it down & replace the problem o-ring. A leaky o-ring won't cause too much loss.  You can slather some food-grade silicone on a seal to keep it from leaking if you don't have a replacement on hand.  Keg-lube (or the generic food-grade silicone) is invaluable.

It's also a good idea to remove, clean and sanitize them before filling a fresh keg.

Answer (score 2):

I try to remove all of the fittings clean them and put them back together every time I fill a keg.  In reality, I end up doing it every second or third time.  So far this hasn't bitten me on the butt, but I know for a fact one day it will.

As for replacing o-rings; I replace them all whenever I get a new keg.  From there, I just keep an eye on them and replace any that leak as Dean said above.

Answer (score 1):

Check for cracks in the rings also. An obvious clue to change them.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this question as a related one to one I just answered.

I'd suggest replacing the post/dip-tube o-rings every time you disassemble them.  Folks have a tendency to overtighten the posts, pinching them, thus making the o-rings unreusable.  The lid o-rings, unless pinched by not paying attention, rarely need replaced.  The o-rings, purchased in bulk, are quite inexpensive from an industrial supplier like McMaster:

> DipTube: ID 5/16", OD 1/2" (AS568A Dash Number 109) McMaster 9452K172 Buna-N $2.21 per 100.
>
> Post: ID 7/16", OD 5/8" (AS568A Dash Number 111) McMaster 9452K23 Buna-N $2.48 per 100.
>
> Lid: ID 3 1/2", OD 4" (AS568A Dash Number 417) McMaster 9452K218 Buna-N $12.69 per 10.

If you have a restaurant supply store in your area, I'd suggest getting a food grade silicone spray or squeeze tube - it doesn't take much of either to make a good seal and is generally cheaper than at the online stores when you figure shipping in.  You should re-lube every time you loosen a fitting with an o-ring.